# Proving two spanning set are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand how I should approach the following question;

Prove the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are equal. $$U = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,3),(−1,2,9)\}$$ and $$W = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid z−3y+3x = 0 \}.$$

I understand that proving this involves proving a set inclusion in both directions, however its not very clear to how the elements/vectors of $W$ show look given the formula to which they must satisfy.

Your help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that both $U$ and $W$ are each dimension $2$.

(*$W$ is dimension $2$ because it can be written as $span\{(1,0,-3),(0,1,3)\}$*)

Since they are the same dimension and both subsets of the same parent space of $\Bbb R^3$, it suffices to merely show inclusion in one direction instead of in both directions.  After all, if you have an $n$ dimensional space, the only $n$-dimensional subspace of it is the original space itself.

So... checking inclusion in the one direction, it suffices to check whether $(1,2,3)$ satisfy $z-3y+3x=0$ and whether $(-1,2,9)$ satisfy $z-3y+3x=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In addition how can I think about the elements of the set $W$. Can you give an example of an element $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that they satisfy the given formula. Thanks

Comment: @dpakasa can I give an example of such an element satisfying the given condition?  Yes... $(1,2,3)$ is an example.  The condition again is that the third element minus three times the second element plus three times the third element is equal to zero.  Here $3 - 3\cdot 2 + 3\cdot 1=0$

Comment: @dpakasa as for "*How can I think about the elements of the set $W$*" you think of them as the elements who satisfy the property that the third element minus three times the second element plus three times the first element equals zero.  No further thought is necessary in most circumstances for it... however if desired, as already alluded to, you could have recognized that $W$ is also able to be expressed as the span of $(1,0,-3)$ and $(0,1,3)$... seen by replacing $x$ by a free variable and $y$ by a free variable... noting that in doing so the value of $z$ is then forced

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help.